# How to get chromium/chrome to open a pdf full screen

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, pdf-reader

When I open a pdf in chromium on my Ubuntu machine or in chrome on my chromebook, it opens it in "continuous" mode. This means you see a number of pages at a time. I can't find a setting to make it full screen or even a single page at a time.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make the PDF full-screen, press <kbd>F11</kbd>.

You can toggle between *fit to page* / *fit to width* with this button in the right bottom corner of the window:

[image: Toggle fit to page/fit to width]

To move through your pages continuously use <kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>↓</kbd>.

Otherwise if you want to move through your PDF in single page view just set the viewer to *fit to page* and use <kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>→</kbd>.

**Edit:** If this does not help, Firefox opens full-screen PDFs in single page view by default.

Comment: F11 does make it full screen but the fit to page doesn't make it show only one of the pages, sadly.

Comment: It the latest version of Chrome this approach works fine!